# Use a calculated result of one request in another request

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to calculate a metric with data coming from two independent tables:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM users
--gives the count of users
SELECT SUM(costs)
FROM costs
--gives the total costs
```

How do I divide total costs/users?

Comment: SELECT 
  (SELECT SUM(costs) FROM costs)
  /
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
FROM users

results in `relation "user" does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did that like this:

```
   WITH costs
     AS (SELECT Sum(costs) AS budget,
                1          AS id
         FROM   costs),
     budget
     AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS users_count,
                1                       AS id
         FROM   users)
SELECT budget / users_count AS Result
FROM   costs
       JOIN budget
         ON costs.id = budget.id
```

That is ugly, but does the job